# iphone two nibs have different x coordinates for center

Tags: iphone, layout, center, nib

Ok this is really odd.

I didn't even know how to phrase the question.
I am using XCode 4.5
I have two views, each with their own NIB. It is possible that one NIB was created in a much earlier version of XCode, and one in 4.2 (I don't remember)

I have an icon that I want to center horizontally.

In one NIB, when I center it, the Frame Rectangle says X/Y coord = 160x46
which makes sense as its centered and near the top of the display

In the other NIB, the Frame rectangle is: X/Y coord = 204x46 yet it is also essentially centered (it's possible it is off by a few px)

If it set the Frame Rect to 160 x 46, then the icon moves way over to the left.

It's like Interface Builder thinks one NIB is wider/denser than the other

They are set to Size: None, Orientation: Portrait
View mode = Scale To fill.

I duplicated them both for Retina4 as I want to layout slightly differently, and the same problem occurs when I set the size to retina 4"

I cant see any settings where I could have messed this up .....

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing dont change from XIB set it from code. For X value you can set

> self.view.center.x

and for Y value

> self.view.center.y